# tidyr::gather - operating on ellipsis

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

The code below is my original intent.

```
gather_df <- function (...) {
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(...) %>% 
    tidyr::gather(key, value, -vs)
}

gather_df(vs)
```

To further generalize, is it possible to operate on the ellipsis?

```
gather_df <- function (...) {
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(...) %>% 
    tidyr::gather(key, value, -...)
}

gather_df(vs)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `enquos` to capture all inputs then evaluate them using `!!!`

```
library(dplyr)
gather_df <- function (...) {
  vars<-enquos(...)
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(!!!vars) %>% 
    tidyr::gather(key, value, -c(!!!vars))
}

gather_df(vs)
gather_df(vs,cyl)
gather_df(vs,cyl,hp)
```

PS: I'm using `rlang 0.3.1`

Comment: Thanks. It runs on rlang 0.3.0.1 but it didn't quite work on 0.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I used quo() instead of enquos() to maintain rlang 0.1.2 compatibility.

```
gather_df <- function (...) {
  vars <- quo(...)
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(!!!vars) %>% 
    tidyr::gather(key, value, -c(!!!vars))
}

gather_df(vs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative argument as character (rlang > 0.1.2).

```
gather_df <- function (...) {
  grp_var <- rlang::sym(...)
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(!!!grp_var) %>% 
    gather(key, value, -!!(grp_var))
}

gather_df("vs")
```